# Change AllowsTransparency at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm currently trying to make a drag&drop-able Tabcontrol

When i change the `AllowsTransparency`-property of a `Window` at runtime I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
```

Is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: As the [documentation states](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.allowstransparency%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you cannot change AllowsTransparency changed after the window has been shown. Set it to `true` in advance.

Comment: Set it at design time and use opaque background color initially.

Comment: My Tabcontrol works kind of like the tabsystem of visual studio: It's a transparent window when you start dragging it but it becomes a full window when you release it again. So I have to change it at runtime

Comment: Why do you have to change `AllowTransparency`? You have to chance the transparency (from 100% to your desired value and back).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Window.AllowsTransparency Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.allowstransparency.aspx) this can solve the problem

```
WindowStyle="None"
```

> AllowsTransparency exists to facilitate the creation of
>   non-rectangular windows, and, consequently, when AllowsTransparency is
>   set to true, a window's WindowStyle property must be set to None.

So to possibility to change AllowsTransparency at runtime answere is **Not possible** You cannot change this property at run time.

My idea in reference to your comment:

> My Tabcontrol works kind of like the tabsystem of visual studio: It's
>   a transparent window when you start dragging it but it becomes a full
>   window when you release it again. So I have to change it at runtime –

Why not create second window with transparence and play with `Hide`. Both could be bound to the same data, so why not switch them? User will not notice. Or just change transparency value from 0 to 100 etc?

Comment: @MyNameIsHans so you cannot I edited my answere. BUT! Let us find workaround, what you want to achieve with changing it?

Comment: @MyNameIsHans also i have added some idea according to your comment!

Comment: Ok. I will try your idea